# Could kibana can import index patterns from elasticsearch indexes automatically?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Now the elasticsearch has many indexes. These indexes pattern like aaa-2016_12_14.log and bbb-2016_12_14.log and others. And it will generate new index everyday, it pattern will be the xxx-YYYY_mm_dd.I want the kibana can automatic import these index to the index pattern. These index patterns will similarly like the aaa,bbb and so on.

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do that by having a `wildcard` pattern for your indexes in `Kibana`. Make sure you create the index in `Kibana` with the same name which you've created the index in ES. Your index pattern in `Kibana` could look something like this:

**aaa-2015*** <-- this could create an index with all your months

**aaa-2015-01*** <--- this could create an index within a month

I'm not sure this works through out all the versions. Keep an eye on that. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851395/kibana-create-index-pattern-strange-behaviour-of-wildcard) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Kulasangar. See you again : ). I mean if the es generate a new index then the kibana will create the same index pattern automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I just used stack soon. I have marked your last answer for me. : )

Comment: Haha great, noted! :)